# How to get a control's location in WP7 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Can anyone please inform me how I can get the location of a control? Apparently `controlName.Margin.Top` 
doesn't work for me. When I put a break-point, I get 0.0 for the Left value when obviously it's not, the control is half way in the screen.

Comment: I think it works. What makes you think it doesnt?

Comment: I get a 0.0 when I put a break point.

Comment: Yes I know that... What i'm trying to say is that it's obviously not 0.0... It's half way in the screen so it can't be 0.0

Comment: Are you talking about the position of the control or the margin of the control?

Comment: Position. I want to know what the position of the Control is on my Canvas. Can you also explain how they differ please?

Comment: We could go on like this for quite a while. The point I'm trying to make is that you're way, *way* to vague in your question. Is the position wrong or is the margin wrong? Or are they both wrong? If they're not supposed to be in the middle of the screen where do you think they should be? What have you tried to do in order to alter their behavior? What does your code look like? Do you get any errors? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's something like

Point position = child.TransformToVisual(ancestor).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

where ancestor is the LayoutRoot or the Page and child is the Control in question.

EDIT: I just read your comment "I want to know what the position of the Control is on my Canvas". ancestor can of course be the direct parent as well.

However in this very case (where the direct parent is a Canvas) the following might be better:
var top = myCanvas.GetTop(child);